# What access right to set of Application pool user to access FILESTREAM file share

Tags: iis, sql-server-2014, filetable

I'm creating a web app using ASP.NET on Windows Server 2012.
I'm using SQL Server 2014 and I have a FileTable the file table maps to the following path `\\CIHOST1\MSSQLSERVER\FileStreamDirectory\AvatarsFT\`
Both SQL Server and IIS are on the same physical machine.

When I setup my website's application pool identity to logon as Administrator the app can read and write files to the path, but when I change to default application pool identity I get access denied exception so that the app can't create or read files from that UNC path. The question is what permission to set and where so that the ApplicationPoolIdentity has access to SQL Server file share. What group should my ApplicationPoolIdentity user be part of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the windows user you are trying to access the fileshare as have
>   SQL server access to the filetable database? Windows share permissions
>   don't apply to filestream shares so, make sure you have permissions in
>   the SQL database.

So the problem was resolved by adding a SQL Server Login for the specified windows user with the following settings:

[image]
[image]